# "improving" OpenCVs Houghtransform for multi-cores

Tags: c++, opencv, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, hough-transform

Please take a look at OpenCVs implementation of Houghtransform [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/hough.cpp),

for example the HoughCircle detection at line 1001. It is meant to be processed on a single CPU core. My question is, if it is possible to optimize this code for multi-core processors by paralellizing certain steps of th Houghtransform, for example the accumulation of edge pixels. As far as I can see, the accumulator starts at line 1058, where you can find two for-loops. Is it possible to stubbornly replace these two by parallel_for_'s (of course not literally)?

Comment: Certainly it is possible to write a parallel hough transform.

Comment: sorry I missed to copy the link. Now its there

Comment: I don't think that you can parallelize it easily, since you always need to process all points, but approximate or smart solutions are possible. See  [here](http://preserve.lehigh.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1073&context=etd), [here](http://www.cse.wustl.edu/~ychen/public/JSP.pdf), [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/026288569190017J).